# getExtras causing app to crash

Tags: java, android, listview, bundle

I am working on an Android App that lets me create an Event in CreateActivity, and than passes the data from CreateActivity to the MainActivity through Bundle and putExtras().

It appears as if I am using .getExtras() or getString() wrong. **The app crashes once the b.getString("TITLE") function is implemented.**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

    ListView listView;
    int lastIndex = -1;
    ArrayList<Event> lstEvents;

    // detail view
    TextView tvTitle, tvTime, tvDate;
    ImageView img;
    View vw_master;

    boolean _isBack = true;

    ImageButton add;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        // get list view
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
        lstEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();

        // // get detail controls
        tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
        tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);

        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        b.getString("TITLE");



            add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.add:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }  

}
```

**CREATEACTIVITY**

```
 public class CreateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText etTitle;
    Button btDate;
    Button btTime;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        // /onclicklistener
        findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm).setOnClickListener(this);

        // edittexts and buttons
        btDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
        etTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
        btTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
    }

    // Will be called via the onClick attribute
    // of the buttons in main.xml
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_confirm:
             String title = etTitle.getText().toString();
             String time = btTime.getText().toString();
             String date = btDate.getText().toString();

            Log.e("LOG", title);
            Log.e("LOG", time);
            Log.e("LOG", date);



            Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
            newBundle.putString("TITLE", title);
            newBundle.putString("TIME", time);
            newBundle.putString("DATE", date);



            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(newBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }

    }

    public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

}
```

Error Log :

```
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.datetracker/com.example.datetracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:146)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5168)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at com.example.datetracker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5200)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-03 15:44:07.117: E/AndroidRuntime(15202):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
```

Comment: check bundle for null before accessing it, its non null when you fill data in bundle in saveInstancestate function. otherwise its null

Comment: @PulkitSethi - the bundle he is using is from the intent extras. However, the null check should still apply since the extras bundle can be null

Comment: please upload your logs output

Comment: When you get exceptions, post the stacktrace/logcat output as part of your question. It should tell you the exact line where you problem is.

Comment: Can you find which line is line 48 in your `onCreate()` and make a comment in your code? That will indicate what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out that the problem was being caused from the fact that when the app is initially opened it is trying to getExtras() on values that haven't been placed yet.

I used this as a simple fix to check if there is any extras at first launch.

> ```
>   Intent intent = getIntent();
>     if (intent.getExtras() == null) {
>         // Do first time stuff here
>     } else {
>         // Do stuff with intent data here
>         Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
>         title = b.getString("TITLE");
>         time = b.getString("TIME");
>         date = b.getString("DATE");
> ```

```
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you didn't initialize lstEvents.
Let's try `lstEvents = new ArrayList<Event>()` in onCreate() methods

Comment: I added that piece, but I still get the same error. My guess is that it might have something to do with the SwipeAdapter that I have.

I am going to post that code and let me know what you think. The SwipeAdapter was associated with another project that used a fragment and different layouts/views.

Comment: Can you post logcat output? It's better to find where is the error :)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare all your variables inside onCreate() method!!!

```
public class WebsiteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_website);

        WebView webView;
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String website = intent.getStringExtra("key");

        //Open website
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webViewId);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(website);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My guess would be that in this line:

```
   Integer id = eventItem.get_Id();
```

get_Id() is returning null, based on the observation that you aren't initializing that field in the new Event() calls and that you haven't gotten into the habit of initializing variable instances yet.

Given that, you'd be passing in null to the view.setId(id) call.  When you do initialiaze it, don't initialize it to 0 as that's not a valid Id for views. you can use NO_ID or a positive number.

Also:
in onCreate() 
You can check that findViewById(R.id.add) is returning a View and not null.  That would cause a NullPointerException at about the right line of code.

Comment: That line is within the adapter, which isn't getting called until the end of `onCreate()`. If this was the error, then `getView()` would show as the top line in the stack trace for the NPE, rather than say it's caused at `MainActivity.onCreate()` line 48

Comment: from ItzHoudini: .."my guess is that it might have something to do with the SwipeAdapter..."

Comment: Then either he has multiple issues and his logcat is from another issue, or he's guessed incorrectly, which is why he asked the question.